# Django with ajax Request

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-urls

I have below code

```
function OpenModal()
{
 var fname="Quartz";
 var mname="Rohit";
 var lname="Patel";

 var url="{% url 'display_modal' %}"+fname +"/"+mname+"/"+lname;
 alert(url);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('divcontent').innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How to execute the above code on click of a button in django templating language.
url is like

```
path('member/search/',
         views.displayModalView, name="display_modal"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ajax does it will prevent a page from reload, this is the magic of ajax. So if you are providing `path`, this can be use for page reload.

Html:

```
<script>
        function OpenModal(){
         var fname="Quartz";
         var mname="Rohit";
         var lname="Patel";
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: "{% url 'display_modal' %}",
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                success: function(param123){
                    dict1 = JSON.parse(param123);
                    let data1 = dict1.test;
                    alert("Successful call do what ever you want");
                    alert(data1);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("sorry");
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

urls.py:
what `url` does it will match the regex with your mentioned url.
the `name='display_modal'` parameter and the `url: "{% url 'display_modal' %}"` that you are mentioning in ajax call would be same.

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^display_modal', views.displayModalView, name='display_modal')
    ]
```

views.py:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
def displayModalView(request):
    #do what ever you want but at the end return Httpresponse with dictionary if you want 
     to use dictionary in your ajax call.
   param123 = {'test': "Hello_world"}
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(param123))
```

Comment: I want to have a get request and pass three parameters i.e. fname,mname and lname to my views in above case its displayModalView(request,fname,mname,lname)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I got the solution. I replaced data: { fname,mname,lname}, and path('member/search/$', that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a jQuery Ajax request inside a normal click() method, like descripted here: [W3C Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

In this case, however, I think you have to declare the url as ***TemplateAsView***, so you can tell Django to immediatly return a template instead of execute a Django view, as described in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/#usage-in-your-urlconf). In the template you can execute the function, as you wish, for example in the template you can insert a call to your function on document ready, and execute when the DOM is loaded, as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp).

To do this you have to change the url, because a *view.someView* in made to search, inside your **view.py**, *the someView function declaration*, but your function is a Javascript so, I presume, you put it inside the template code.

I see that your code is a Javascript function, so I try to figure why you have to call a function like this with Django template system, as a template call, and you can't call the function directly. I think that doing as you want you force a DOM reload everytime and, I think, there are several method to open a modal without a page refresh.

Comment: I want to open a modal window. Also in modal window I want to pass parameter from main window to modal window. That's why I have used fname,mname,lname parameters. If i use   var url="{% url 'display_modal' Quartz Rohit Patel %} then I get the desired result. But I want to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick to your button and the value of that should equal to your function
like this

```
<button onclick='show()' something else ... ></button>
```

------------------------------ javascript--------------------------------------------------

```
function show(){
        something else ...
}
```

you can also see jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)